# couch_peruser in CouchDB 2.0 not working

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I am working on a use case where every user has to have his/her private `couchdb` database. I came across the `couch_peruser` configuration flag in `CouchDB 2.0`  [CouchDB Official Link](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/couch-peruser.html). Setting this flag to true create a private database for every user in the `_users` database.

Upon installing `CouchDB 2.0` and setting the `couch_peruser` flag, I found that it doesn't work. It is not creating any private database for the users. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Have you restarted CouchDB after having changed the configuration?

Comment: Yes, I restarted but is doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The couch_peruser feature is broken in 2.0 as detailed here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-3246